# Improve SQL select query execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL query which throws a database timeout error.

```
select distinct payment_gateway_id 
from tblPaymentGatewayLog 
where entity_id in (select entity_id from tblentityList)
```

`tblPaymentGatewayLog` only has like 10 records, but `tblentityList` can have over 20000 records hence making the query slow.

I tried using inner join instead of the IN query but still no difference. Any possible way of improving the query execution time?

Comment: What does the execution plan reveal?

Comment: Can you provide DDL along with all indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct payment_gateway_id 
from tblPaymentGatewayLog pgl
where exists (select 1 from tblentityList el where el.entity_id = pgl.entity_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too am a fan of `exists`:

```
select distinct gl.payment_gateway_id 
from tblPaymentGatewayLog gl
where exists (select 1 from tblentityList el where el.entity_id  = gl.entity_id);
```

This is still tricky, because of the `select distinct`.  So, I also recommend an index on `(tblPaymentGatewayLog, entity_id)`.  `tblentityList` is so small that I don't think an index would help.

Answer (score 0):

`Exists` is faster than `IN` and `join` will return duplicate records.

my preference is `Exists`:

```
select distinct payment_gateway_id 
from tblPaymentGatewayLog T1
where exists (select 1 from tblentityList T2 where T2.entity_id = T1.entity_id)
```